# How do I wrap a constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

I have this JavaScript:

```
var Type = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

var t = new Type();
```

Now I want to add this:

```
var wrap = function(cls) {
    // ... wrap constructor of Type ...
    this.extraField = 1;
};
```

So I can do:

```
wrap(Type);
var t = new Type();

assertEquals(1, t.extraField);
```

**[EDIT]** I'd like an instance property, not a class (static/shared) property.

The code executed in the wrapper function should work as if I had pasted it into the real constructor.

The type of `Type` should not change.

Comment: By what I understand, you want to add an additional property to the constructor? so that further new instances have that property?

Comment: May be you need simply to change prototype of `Type` inside `wrap()` function. For example: `var wrap = function(cls) { cls.prototype.extraField=1; };`? Or may be is best to create new `Type2` inherited from `Type` with additional `extraField` member?

Comment: Can you describe your issue more detail?

Comment: I'd like an instance property, not a class (static/shared) property. The code executed in the wrapper function should work as if I had pasted it into the real constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

update: [An updated version here](http://jsfiddle.net/EsWbu/8/)

what you were actually looking for was extending Type into another Class. There are a lot of ways to do that in JavaScript. I'm not really a fan of the `new` and the `prototype` methods of building "classes" (I prefer the parasitic inheritance style better), but here's what I got:

```
//your original class
var Type = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

//our extend function
var extend = function(cls) {

    //which returns a constructor
    function foo() {

        //that calls the parent constructor with itself as scope
        cls.apply(this, arguments)

        //the additional field
        this.extraField = 1;
    }

    //make the prototype an instance of the old class
    foo.prototype = Object.create(cls.prototype);

    return foo;
};

//so lets extend Type into newType
var newType = extend(Type);

//create an instance of newType and old Type
var t = new Type('bar');
var n = new newType('foo');


console.log(t);
console.log(t instanceof Type);
console.log(n);
console.log(n instanceof newType);
console.log(n instanceof Type);
```

Comment: From your console output, I'd like to extend the function stored in `constructor`. The new field should show up next to `name`, not next to `constructor`.

Comment: so what you really want to do is create another constructor? or just add to the existing?

Comment: I want to extend the existing constructor.

Comment: instead of `cls.prototype.constructor.call(this, name)`, I'd do `cls.call(this, name)`. Same function, and no need to worry if the `.constructor` property is actually present. The danger of `foo.prototype = new cls();` is that `cls` may be a function that requires arguments. That's where `foo.prototype = Object.create(cls.prototype)` is preferred.

Comment: @amnotiam interesting. Now I learned something new. But `Object.create` is ECMA5, how would you do this in older browsers?

Comment: [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/uHxLC/) shows the classic fix. It only emulates the "object creation with prototype" part of `Object.create`, but that's all you need here.