# why prototype javascript not works in that case

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

My case(why "test1" not appear in alert window):

```
var Parent=function(){
    this.test1= function(){ 
        alert("test1");
    }
}

var Child=function(){
   this.prototype=new Parent();
}

var test=new Child();
test.test1();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c3sUM/2/  (same code online to try)
​

Thanks

Comment: Please use function declarations rather than not function expressions. There is no benefit here for using expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you didn't assign the `Child`'s prototype but instead, made a property `prototype` in the instance of `Child` which points to an instance of `Parent` .

[instead, do this](http://jsfiddle.net/c3sUM/4/):

```
var Child = function(){};        // create constructor
Child.prototype = new Parent();  // assign instance of parent to constructor's
                                 // prototype
```

[A similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10101604/575527) might help

Comment: @Yosef sorry i wasn't clear. I updated the answer with a demo.

Comment: @Yosef sorry, I don't know any methods to do this using prototypes. However, you could take a look [in this article](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) for more insights.

Comment: @Yosef: Inside Child, you can do `Parent.apply(this, arguments);`. It won't technically inherit unless you make `Child.prototype` a `Parent` object. `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);` and put the method on `Parent.prototype`.

Comment: @amnotiam I think [I have a similar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10101604/575527) answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be much clearer using function declarations:

```
// Parent constructor
function Parent() {}

// Methods of Parent.prototype are inherited by 
// instances of parent
Parent.prototype.test1 = function() {
    alert('test 1');
}

// Child constructor
function Child(){}

// Make Child.prototype an instance of Parent so 
// instances inherit from Child and Parent
Child.prototype = new Parent();

// Instance inherits from Child (and hence Parent);
var child = new Child();

child.test1();  // 'test 1'
```

The only reason to use function expressions over declarations in this case is if you want to dynamically create the constructors based on some other logic.